# Catchable fatal error inside WordPress function

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function magazine_vertical($atts){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'slug' => '',
        'title' => '',
        'limit' => '5',
    ),$atts));

    //The Query
    query_posts('showposts=1&orderby=date&order=DESC&category_name='.$slug);

    //The Loop
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $return .= '<div class="magazine-vertical">';
        $return .= '<div class="magazine-vertical-title-category"><span class="magazine-vertical-title">'.$title.'</span><span class="magazine-vertical-category"><a href="'. get_term_by('slug', $slug, 'category').'">More articles</a></span></div>';
        $return .= '<div class="magazine-vertical-large">';
        $return .= '<div class="magazine-vertical-large-1">';
        $return .= '<div class="magazine-vertical-large-thumbnail">';
        $return .= '<a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" title="">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'magazine-vertical').'</a>';
        $return .= '</div>';
        $return .= '<div class="magazine-vertical-large-subtitle">';
        $return .= '<a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" title="">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
        $return .= '</div>';
        $return .= '<div class="magazine-vertical-large-date">';
        $return .= get_the_time('F j, Y');
        $return .= '</div>';
        $return .= '<div class="magazine-vertical-large-excerpt">';
        $return .= get_the_excerpt();
        $return .= '</div>';
        $return .= '</div>';
        $return .= '</div>';
    endwhile;
    endif;

    //Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();

    return $return;
}
add_shortcode('magazine_vertical', 'magazine_vertical');
```

Function above produces: `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted`

Problem is in this part:

```
$return .= '<div class="magazine-vertical-title-category"><span class="magazine-
vertical-title">'.$title.'</span>
<span class="magazine-vertical-category"><a href="'. get_term_by('slug', $slug, 'category').'">More articles</a></span></div>';
```

Witout this code works (I need this part with "More articles):

```
<a href="'. get_term_by('slug', $slug, 'category').'">More articles</a>
```

[magazine_vertical slug=my-category] is shortcode which I am using inside page.
I get it all work ok, except this part where **I have to get category link from slug atts**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Wordpress,  **$output: Constant OBJECT, ARRAY_A, or ARRAY_N**

```
  function get_term_by($field, $value, $taxonomy, $output = OBJECT, $filter = 'raw') { }
```

Default output is `object`, you can't able to convert the object into string.

You can try `get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );` Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link

Comment: get_term_link( $slug, 'category'); was everything I needed. I should ask before, all day I am fighting with this. Thank you.